# Android virtual device is not working continuously?

Tags: java, android

the android virtual device is showing out of memory but have used wipe data many times still the device is not working is there any other was to use the same virtual device without making a new one[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ1DB.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase your storage from virtual device setting or wipe clear data
instead using of default virtual machine or emulator of android you must have to try genymotion its is free for person use and it is way better then default. here is a url to genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

-->Simply "Wipe data" to fix this issue.
-->If it doesn't work, go to emulated device and enable developer options > enable usb debugging
or
It's better if you uninstall the app from the emulator